# Fibonacci sequence and convergence of $t_n=\cfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Fibonacci sequence define as: $x_1=x_2=1 , x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$ for $n \ge 1$ prove the sequence $t_n=\cfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is convergent.

First of all I start by calculating some of the first terms of the $t_n$ sequence:

$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
t_n:&\frac11&\frac21&\frac32&\frac{5}3&\frac{8}{5}&\frac{13}{8}
\end{array}$

It seems for even values of $n$ the sequence is decreasing and for odd values of $n$ it is increasing.

To prove the first statement (where $n=2k$) , I should prove $t_{2k}- t_{2k+2}\ge 0$ :

$$\cfrac{x_{2k+1}}{x_{2k}}- \cfrac{x_{2k+3}}{x_{2k+2}} \ge0$$

$$\cfrac{x_{2k+1} \cdot x_{2k+2}- x_{2k+3} \cdot x_{2k}}{x_{2k} \cdot x_{2k+2}} \ge 0$$

$$x_{2k+1} \cdot x_{2k+2} \ge x_{2k+3} \cdot x_{2k}$$

$$x_{2k+1} \cdot (x_{2k}+x_{2k+1}) \ge  x_{2k} \cdot (x_{2k+1}+x_{2k+2})$$

$$x_{2k+1} \times x_{2k+1} \ge x_{2k} \times x_{2k+2}$$
Here I don't khow how to proceed.

Comment: there's a general form for the Fibonacci sequence that doesn't involve recursion. Alternatively you could set up a stochastic matrix and use linear algebra

Comment: @person This is a problem from sequences chapter of the book I am reading, So I should do it with sequences.

Comment: Prove that it is a bounded sequence. After that, prove it can have only one limit point.

Comment: Does this help - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739229/fibonacci-sequence-golden-ratio

Comment: @CalvinLin So in order to prove it, I have to use  "Fibonacci relationship $x_n=\frac {F_n}{F_n+F_{n-1}}=\frac 1{1+x_{n-1}}$" And isn't possible to continue the my approach?

Comment: @Soheil There could be many ways of proving it (like using Binet's formula), so I disagree with "I have to use Fibonacci relationship in this very particular way". I agree with "I have to use Fibonacci relationship somehow".

Comment: Can you prove that $t_{n+1}=1+1/t_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that this sequence converges to the golden ratio...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241908/prove-that-this-sequence-converges-to-the-golden-ratio) or [several similar posts](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D1%2B%5Cfrac1%7Bx_n%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** *I'm not 100% certain that this can be an acceptable answer, so I'm asking others to help me improve it, but this is what I've thought about the problem.*

Writing $t_n$ as $t_n=1+\frac{1}{t_{n-1}}, n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $t_0=\infty$, we see that
$$(t_n)=\{1,2,3/2,5/3,8/5,13/8,\dots\}.$$
Like you have observed, the even-index terms are decreasing and the odd-index terms are decreasing. Let's prove this by induction. The proposition is that $t_{2n}>t_{2(n+1)}$
$$
\implies\frac{1}{t_{2n}}<\frac{1}{t_{2(n+1)}}\implies 1+\frac{1}{t_{2n}}<1+\frac{1}      {t_{2(n+1)}}\implies t_{2n+1}<t_{2(n+1)+1}
$$
This proves that the odd-index terms are increasing. Similarly, we start with the proposition $t_{2n-1}<t_{2n+1}$
$$
\implies \frac{1}{t_{2n-1}}>\frac{1}{t_{2n+1}}\implies 1+\frac{1}{t_{2n-1}}>1+\frac{1}{t_{2n+1}}\implies t_{2n}>t_{2(n+1)}
$$
which proves that the even-index terms are decreasing.

Observe that $0<t_{2n}<2$ and $1\leq t_{2n-1}<2$. Thus these are bounded and hence by the *Monotone Convergence Theorem*, the subsequences converge. Since these are subsequences of the given sequence $(t_n)$, we can conclude that $(t_n)$ also converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$X_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right]=\frac{a^n-b^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$
So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_{n+1}}{X_n}=a=\frac{1|+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: I don't think OP is allowed to use the Euler-Binet Formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You van use this formula:

$$x_n\leqslant\big(\frac53\big)^n$$

$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\leqslant\frac53$$

Note: The proof of this formula is in "Discrete and Combinatorial  Mathematics, an applied introductioc" ,Ralph. P. Grimaldi

Answer (score 0):

Did anybody recall [Cassini's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) identitiy?
$$x_n^2=x_{n+1}x_{n-1}+(-1)^{n+1}$$
For odd $n$,
$$x_{2k+1}^2=x_{2k}x_{2k+2}+1$$