# Does the recurring succession $X_{n+1} = 1+\frac{1}{X_n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm working on some calculus exercises and came across this one. It is familiar yet not the same as the $\mathcal e$ one. The question states:

Given $X_0 = 1$ and $X_{n+1} = 1+\frac{1}{X_n}$, for $n \geq 0$.

Show that it converges and find its limit.

---

So I tried to approach this by looking at its behave. Does $\frac{1}{X_n}$ converge to $0$ ? But it's not trivial answer. I also tried to look at $X_{n+1} $ expressed as a function of $X_0$ but was hard to see if I could simplify it in one-line formula. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that, if the sequence does converge, then it converges to a root of the polynomial $x^2 - x - 1$, by letting $n \to \infty$ in your recurrence.

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518739/prove-that-the-sequence-a-n-defined-by-a-0-1-a-n1-1-frac-1a-n)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $Y_n=X_n-\phi$; then
$$|Y_{n+1}|=\left|1+\frac{1}{Y_n+\phi}-\phi\right|=\left|\frac{(1-\phi)Y_n}{Y_n+\phi}\right|\leqslant|(1-\phi)Y_n|,$$
because $Y_n+\phi=X_n\geqslant 1$ clearly.  As $|1-\phi|<1$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n=0$.