# Approximation of $x^2-x-1 = 0$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series

An exercise in Calculus With Applications by Peter D. Lax confused me, here is the original text:

**1.34**. Solve $x^2 − x − 1 = 0$ as follows. Restate the equation as $x = 1 + 1/x$, which suggests the sequence of approximations
$$x_0 = 1,\quad x_1 = 1+ 1/x_0,\quad x_2=1 + 1/x_1, ...$$

Explain the following items to prove that the sequence converges to a solution.

(a) $x_0 < x_2 < x_1$

(b) $x_0 < x_2 < x_4 < ··· < x_5 < x_3 < x_1$

(c) The even sequence $x_{2k}$ increases to a limit $L$, and the odd sequence $x_{2k+1}$ decreases to a limit $R ≥ L$.

(d) The distances $(x_{2k+3} −x_{2k+2})$ satisfy $(x_{2k+3} −x_{2k}+2) < 1/x_4^2(x_{2k+1} -x_{2k}).$

(e) $R=L=\lim\limits_{k\to∞}x_k$ is a solution to $x^2 −x−1 = 0.$

For (c) I have trouble explaining the increment of the even-numbered sequence, although it is obvious by listing a few figures. I can tell that the even terms are bounded, but I can't verify that the even terms are increasing. Please help me please

Comment: Step c) is straightforward isnt it? If a sequence is strictly increasing and bounded from above it automatically converges to a limit. Do you mean you need help with b)?

Comment: Yes, I think the author is prompting me to list some numbers and then guess the patterns that these numbers may show. But I struggled to prove that this rule is logically correct.

Comment: argue by induction

Comment: So your problem is with step b)?

Comment: This is quite a popular [sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518739/prove-that-the-sequence-a-n-defined-by-a-0-1-a-n1-1-frac-1a-n) and [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520262/show-that-a-n1-1-frac1a-n-converges/2520335).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof for step (b):

First we notice that
$$
x_{i+2}=1+1/x_{i+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+1/x_i}=1+\frac{x_i}{x_i+1}=\frac{2x_i+1}{x_i+1}
$$
and $x_i>0$. Next, we try to prove that the two-step is strictly increasing
$$
x_{i+2}>x_i\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{2x_i+1}{x_i+1}>x_i\\
\Leftrightarrow x_i+1>x_i^2
$$
So in order to show that the two step is strictly increasing we need to prove that the last inequality holds true for all $i$. We do this by induction

- Initial step: $x_0=1\Rightarrow1+1>1$ (Here we use that we are actually talking about the **even** indices)
- Induction step: assume that $x_i+1>x_i^2$, now show that $x_{i+2}+1>x_{i+2}^2$.
  $$
  x_{i+2}+1>x_{i+2}^2\\
  \Leftrightarrow \frac{2x_i+1}{x_i+1}+1>\frac{(2x_i+1)^2}{(x_i+1)^2}\\
  \Leftrightarrow \frac{3x_i+2}{x_i+1}>\frac{(2x_i+1)^2}{(x_i+1)^2}\\
  \Leftrightarrow (3x_i+2)(x_i+1)>(2x_i+1)^2\\
  \Leftrightarrow x_i+1>x_i^2\\
  $$

The proof for the decreasing odd indices works the same way.

To show that the even indices are always strictly below the odd indices we observe that
$$
x_{2i}<x_{2i+1}\\
\Leftrightarrow x_{2i}<1+1/x_{2i}
\Leftrightarrow x_{2i}^2<x_{2i}+1
$$
which we have already proven.

Comment: What a neat proof why I can't see it in any book. You are a master of inductive proof. Thank you all for your help.